# How to get a line with a specfic text from HTML

Tags: python, html, web

I'm trying to get a line with a specfic text on a html code.

For example in this web:
https://animeflv.net/anime/otome-game-no-hametsu-flag-shika-nai-akuyaku-reijou-ni-tensei-shiteshimatta

The code inside:

```py
var episodes = [[8,54514],[7,54485],[6,54456],[5,54430],[4,54400],[3,54367],[2,54327],[1,54271]];
```

I want to know how can I get that exact line, with Python.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
url = 'https://animeflv.net/anime/otome-game-no-hametsu-flag-shika-nai-akuyaku-reijou-ni-tensei-shiteshimatta'
r = requests.get(url)
for line in r.text.splitlines():
    if 'var episodes =' in line:
        break

print(line)
```

Comment: omg thanks i was doing a lot of splitlines examples and didnt got any, thanks :)